# Doctrine : PostgreSQL group by different than select

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine, aggregation

I have two tables :

**user** and **activityHistory** (that has a key to the user)

I am trying to query activityHistory while grouping by user and postgreSQL does not allow me to do that WHILE Sqlite does allow me

```
        return $qb
        ->select('a.id')
        ->leftJoin('a.user', 'user')
        ->leftJoin(
            ActivityHistory::class,
            'b',
            'WITH',
            'a.id = b.id AND a.createdAt > b.createdAt'
        )
        ->groupBy('user.id')
        ->orderBy( 'a.createdAt','ASC' )
        ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

I am getting this error only with postgreSQL : Grouping error: 7 ERROR:  column "a0_.id" must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or be used in an aggregate function

The point is I don't want to `groupBy` activityHistory id, I only want it to be selected, how can I do ? (I heard about aggregate but I think this works only with functions like `SUM` etc)

Comment: You must use an aggregate function when grouping by field. Specify what result you want to get, or better add example data and expected result to the problem

Comment: I want to get the result of this, executing on Sqlite. Here is an example of a potential result : 
 array:2 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "id" => 6
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "id" => 19
  ]
]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let's clarify how aggregation works. Aggregation is the act of grouping by certain field(s) and selecting either those fields or calling aggregation functions and passing ungrouped fields.

You misunderstand how this works - hence the question -, but let me provide you a few very simple examples:

## Example 1

Let's consider that there is a town and there are individuals living in that town. Each individual has an eye color, but, if you are wondering what the eye color of the people of the town is, then your question does not make sense, because the group itself does not have an eye color, unless specified otherwise.

## Example 2

Let's modify the example above by grouping the people of the town by eye color. Such an aggregation will have a row for all existent eye colors and you can select the eye color, along with the average age, number of individuals, etc. as you like, because you are grouping by eye color

## Your example

You have users and they are performing actions. So, an activity is performed by a single user, but a user may perform many activities. So, if you want to group by your user id, then the "eye color" that you are not grouping by here is the history id.

You will have a single record for any user, so you are grouping multiple history items into the same row and after the grouping, asking about the history item's id does not exist.

But, you can use `string_agg(some_column, ',')` which will take all the values you have and put them all into a string of values separated by comma.

You can `explode(',', '$yourvalues)` in PHP to convert such a value into an array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if I misunderstood how it works, how come my request gives me expected results on Sqlite ? (But not on postgreSQL). What i exactly want is first record of activityHistory grouped by user

Comment: @alexandre-mace SQLite is not a very serious RDBMS, it is for lightweight operations and it is quite possible that it does not enfore some rules. Let's focus on your PostgreSQL problem instead. You have 1 user by each user and 0, 1 or more actions by user. How do you want to show a single history id per resulting rows? There is no guarantee that it would be a single record. You need to understand that the fact that you ask for a single history id is in conflict with the fact that there can be more ids. Use an aggregae function, such as `string_agg` to add history id to the aggregation.

Comment: Getting only first result can be done by a join on the table itself + condition which is what I have done (see my code example). I found a pretty close example here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69625719/doctrine-query-language-latest-row-per-group. Can you please provide an example of a working doctrine query + the aggregate function ?

Comment: @alexandre-mace I have not used Doctrine since 2020 and I have no doctrine environment ready for testing. If I were you, I would first write the raw query and when that works, I would try to write the Doctrine code. If Doctrine is not supporting some of the features I was speaking about, then you always have the option of creating a `view` or `materialized view` in Postgres and load the values from that using the simplest Doctrine features.

Comment: @alexandre-mace let me know if you have trouble writing the raw query, I can help you with that. Once you have the raw query, you will also know what you want to achieve with Doctrine. Then you can try implementing the Doctrine equivalent. At that stage we can look into the problems you may encounter. Also, currently I work in MySQL, so I have no Doctrine env either, but as far as I know there are online Postgres fiddles, so I should be able to conduct Postgres experiments if you have trouble in writing the raw query.